# ChannelInputStream skip method is very slow

Tags: java, nio

I have following piece of test code:

```
    try {
        InputStream is;
        Stopwatch.start("FileInputStream");
        is = new FileInputStream(imageFile.toFile());
        is.skip(1024*1024*1024);
        is.close();
        Stopwatch.stop();

        Stopwatch.start("Files.newInputStream");
        is = Files.newInputStream(imageFile);
        is.skip(1024*1024*1024);
        is.close();
        Stopwatch.stop();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

and I have following output:

```
Start: FileInputStream
FileInputStream : 0 ms
Start: Files.newInputStream
Files.newInputStream : 3469 ms
```

Do you have any idea what is going on? Why skip is so slow in the second case?

I need to use InputStreams acquired from channels because my test have shown that best for my task is to have two threads reading from file simultaneously (and I can notice any improvement only when I am using Streams from Channels).

During tests I figured out that I can do something like this:

```
    SeekableByteChannel sbc = Files.newByteChannel(imageFile);
    sbc.position(1024*1024*1024);
    is = Channels.newInputStream(sbc);
```

which takes only avg. 28ms but that does not help me a lot because to use that I would have to make major API changes.

My platform:

```
Linux galileo 3.11.0-13-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 07:38:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source, it appears that the default implementation of `skip()` is actually reading through (and discarding) the stream content until it reaches the target position:

```
public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
    long remaining = n;
    int nr;

    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int size = (int)Math.min(MAX_SKIP_BUFFER_SIZE, remaining);
    byte[] skipBuffer = new byte[size];
    while (remaining > 0) {
        nr = read(skipBuffer, 0, (int)Math.min(size, remaining));
        if (nr < 0) {
            break;
        }
        remaining -= nr;
    }

    return n - remaining;
}
```

The `SeekableByteChannel#position()` method probably just updates an offset pointer, which doesn't actually require any I/O.  Presumably, `FileInputStream` overrides the `skip()` method with a similar optimization.  The documentation supports this theory:

> This method may skip more bytes than are remaining in the backing file. This produces no exception and the number of bytes skipped may include some number of bytes that were beyond the EOF of the backing file. Attempting to read from the stream after skipping past the end will result in -1 indicating the end of the file.

On platter disks or network storage, this could have a significant impact.

Comment: What do you think - is this a bug in ChannelInputStream implementation? Why there is reading instead of calling `position()`?

Comment: It only seems like a bug because you are dealing with files.  `ChannelInputStream` is not specific to files; it could, for instance, wrap a stream that does not support jumping to an arbitrary position.  Consider a network stream: it does not have a fixed length, and you cannot "jump ahead" without reading whatever data precedes the seek location.  Why `Files.newInputStream()` creates a `ChannelInputStream` instead of a `FileInputStream` is a valid question, and I do not have an answer for you.

Comment: Ok, so I will leave this without reporting a bug. I think the easiest option for me is to wrap channel in my own implementation of InputStream which I will be able to pass to my API.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the range with `GetObjectRequest.setRange` to have the same behavior of `skip`.

```
GetObjectRequest req = new GetObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, "myfile.zip");
req.setRange(1024); // start download skiping 1024 bytes
S3ObjectInputStream in = client.getObject(req).getObjectContent();
// read "in" while not eof
```

I used this to avoid `SocketTimeoutException` on my implementation.
Each time I got a `SocketTimeoutException` I restart the download using the `setRange` to skip the bytes that I already downloaded.